# File is not deleted when using the remove() function

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program in C++ that deletes any file that the user wants to delete. All the code seems to be well written, but when I run the program the file that I ask to be deleted is not actually deleted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char eliminar[100];

    cout << "File name to delete: ";
    cin >> eliminar;

    remove(eliminar);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says, you are typing in a relative path, but the current working directory of the program is not what you think it is, so the file is not found.

Comment: `remove()` will tell you that it is failing (via its return-value:  -1 for an error, or 0 for success) and if it returned -1/error, you can then look at the value of `errno` (or call `perror("remove");` to find out *why* it failed.